# How to convert date into string in hive?

Tags: hive

I have
**date_sub('2020-08-20',2)**. I need to get current system date as string,instead of passing my own date.
Hive version is Hive 0.12.0-cdh5.1.2. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you need current time in `YYYY-MM-DD` format, you may use
`SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp(), 'yyyy-MM-dd')`
But be warned that it may slow down the query since it is going to be evaluated for every row. If the date is the only part you need, you better pass it from outside.

Alternatively if Hive ver. is 2.0 and above, you may use
`SELECT from_unixtime(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyy-MM-dd')`
It will be evaluated once at the beginning of the query but remain the same until the end of execution.